# read a tab delimited txt file into matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I am trying to read a **tab delimited txt file in MatLab**.
The file has columns composed of numbers, text, dates, datetimes, everything you can think of. Some of the columns have very long sentences in them, with commas and everything.

it exceeds the row limit of excel (i have about 1.5 million rows) so I can not convert it to a CSV or an XLSX file.

I have tried the following:

```
tableDataEDM = tdfread(pathDataEDM,'\t');
```

I get back 'need the statistics and machine learning toolbox'
I dont have it

```
tableDataEDM = dlmread(pathDataEDM,'\t');
```

Mismatch between file and format character vector.
I get back 'Trouble reading 'Numeric' field from file'

this is because the file has text and numbers and dates and everything else. dlmread likes numeric data i guess

```
       tableDataEDM = readtable(pathDataEDM,'Delimiter','\t','ReadVariableNames',true);

I get back:
    Error using readtable (line 197)
    Reading failed at line 6. All lines of a text file must have the same number of delimiters. Line 6 has 10
    delimiters, while preceding lines have 32.

    Note: readtable detected the following parameters:
    'HeaderLines', 0, 'Format', '%q%q%q%q%D%D%D%q%q%q%q%q%q%q%q%q%q%q%q%q%q%q%D%D%q%q%q%q%q%q%q%q%q'

    Error in Edm_FinderComp_CrossOver (line 33)
    tableDataEDM = readtable(pathDataEDM,'Delimiter','\t','ReadVariableNames',false);
```

I am not sure why it says this though. I can import this data into python very easily. Is there something I am missing to try and get this into matlab?

any help on import tab delimited txt files is appreciated. I have not tried text scan because it looks painful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html). This will put each column in a separate cell in `tableDataEDM`. Assuming that for each row, you have an `int` \t `int` \t `string`:

```
tableDataEDM = textscan(fopen(pathDataEDM),'%d %d %s')
```

The last argument, `'%d %d %s'` you should change to match your formatting.

Comment: tableDataEDM = textscan(fopen(pathDataEDM),'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s','delimiter','\t')    Thanks, I tried this but it did not end up working because some of the tab delimited rows roll onto the next row.... so when you open the textscaned table data from one row ends up being on two or three different rows sometimes.... When you open the file in notepad++ it looks like this, but in regular notepad the rows are fine.

Comment: Hmm that's weird, it seems like your file is not formatted in a consistent way, which will make it hard for this method to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using the import wizard and changing the delimiter to tabs? Just drag the file into the workspace window and the wizard will appear.