# Importing ASCII tab-delimited line by line with spaces in values

Tags: matlab, csv

Matlab is not splitting lines correctly that are tab-delimited with spaces between words. How do I get that to work?

For instance, say I have a file with these two lines I want to extract, the first is a header line and the second is one row of data:

```
#DATA_NAME    field1    field2    field3
DATA_NAME    14    A String    34.1
```

(delimiters are tabs but I'm showing here with multiple spaces)

I wrote a custom parser that should result in a table with:

```
field1       field2      field3
______       ______      ______
  14        A String      34.1
```

What I'm seeing is something like:

```
field1       field2     field3
______       ______     ______
  14           A        String
```

I have a solution using the `split()` function going line by line with `fgetl`, that works if there are no spaces in the entries. Doing:

```
splitted = split(line, '\t')
```

doesn't seem to work. I did some checking, and the delimiters don't == '\t'...

(I have to use my custom parser because there are lots of different types of data in one file, each with different numbers of columns and different headers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for splitting by tab:

```
splitted = strsplit(aLineOfText, '\t');
```

(It treats the lines differently and made me re-work my script, but seems to work correctly.)

Answer (score 1):

Similar question to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43506729/read-a-tab-delimited-txt-file-into-matlab). You could try:

```
C = textscan(fopen(filename),'%s %d %s %d');
```

This line yelds a cell C with all the values. Check out Matlab's [textscan](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

### use `char(09)` instead of `'\t'`

I can't list them exactly but I noticed that some of Matlab string parser recognise `'\t'` as a proper <kbd>TAB</kbd> character, but some other don't recognise it and treat it as 2 separate characters `'\'` and `'t'`.

example:

```
>> double('\t')
ans =
    92   116
```

This has caused me trouble even while using `textscan` in the past, so now except for `fprintf` where I know it works, everywhere else I always use the ascii code `09` for the tab character, instead of the shorthand notation `'\t'`.

For example:

```
tabc = char(09) ;
C= textscan( s , '%s' , 'delimiter',tabc ) ; % or in any other function using 'delimiters'
```

And to demonstrate the first example:

```
>> double('\t')
ans =
    92   116
>> double(tabc)
ans =
     9
```

---

Sometimes it makes no difference, but if you have trouble dealing with <kbd>TAB</kbd> characters, using the exact ascii code will save you from wondering if it has been interpreted correctly or not ...